# Differentiability of restriction of $ f\implies$ differentiability of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Let's consider $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ and assume that $f_{\mid N\cap M}:N\cap M\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at point $a$. Further $N$ a neigborhood of $a$. Show that $f$ is also differenitable at $a$ and that $f'(a)=f_{\mid N\cap M}'(a)$.

**My approach:**

Due to differentiability of $f_{\mid N\cap M}$ at point $a$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ we find a $\delta_1 >0$ such that
$$
\text{for all } x\in N\cap M \text{ with }|x-a|<\delta_1\implies \Big|\frac{f_{\mid N\cap M}(x)-f_{\mid N\cap M}(a)}{x-a}-f_{\mid N\cap M}'(a)\Big|<\epsilon.
$$
As $N$ is a neigborhood of $a$ there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that $N_{\delta_2}(a):=\{x\in M\mid |x-a|<\delta_2\}\subset N$. Of course for all $x\in N_{\delta_2}(a)$ we have $f(x)=f_{\mid N\cap M}(x)$. We set $\delta:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}>0$. So for all $x\in M$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ it follows that $x\in N$ and
$$
\Big|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f_{\mid N\cap M}'(a)\Big|=\Big|\frac{f_{\mid N\cap M}(x)-f_{\mid N\cap M}(a)}{x-a}-f_{\mid N\cap M}'(a)\Big|<\epsilon.
$$
So $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and because of the uniqueness of the derivative it must be $f'(a)=f_{\mid N\cap M}'(a)$.

---

In our lecture the professor showed this statement differently by defining a new function ... his approach seems much longer and more complicated. So I am wondering if my apporach is correct?

Comment: Can you easily describe the function your professor defined?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, No I don't quite remember...

Comment: Your proof is how I would go about proving this, so I wondered if your professor did something equivalent to considering the restriction of $f$ to the intersection, but maybe it looked different.